# Unrecognized selector sent to instance and crash in main.m in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, selector, segue

Hi everyone I cannot understand this so I'm searching for your help.
Here it is... I'm working on a storyboard for iOS and during the prepareForSegue method i am trying to set a property of the viewcontroller that will be loaded.

Right here I get a crash pointing at the center line of main.m and here is the message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewController setDetails:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8880b80'
```

here is the method prepareForSegue where I ended up looking for mistakes following the exception:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"cellSegue"])
  {
    AppTestDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    detailViewController.details = self.detailsList[indexPath.row];
  }
}
```

Well.. self.detailsList is nothing but an array of Details items.
where the details property is declared in the AppTestDetailViewController.h like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Details.h"
#import "DetailCell.h"


@interface AppTestDetailViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) Details *details;

@end
```

So... i can't understand where the problem is setting the property.
Obviously I'm missing something...
I hope this is clear to you and thanks you a lot for your help!

Comment: It looks like self.detailsList doesn't contain items of type Detail.  Can you inspect that array by putting a breakpoint on the line where you assign it to details and tell us what the contents are?

Comment: I already checked the content of self.detailsList and it contains 3 Details items with their properties setted correctly.

Comment: you know, I wonder if "details" is a reserved keyword.  Try changing your variable name to something like "myDetails"

Comment: @Bek It's not the problem. The problem is that the view controller instance is of class `UITableViewController` and not its custom subclass, `AppTestDetailViewController`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message

```
-[UITableViewController setDetails:]: unrecognized selector ...
```

shows that `detailViewController` is not an instance of `AppTestDetailViewController` as you expect, but "only" a `UITableViewController`.

One possible reason could be that you did not set the "Custom Class" for the controller
in the storyboard file.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.... I tried to set that parameter way in advance while creating the storyboard, but somehow it didn't accepted the change at the time... now it did! thanks a lot again!

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! It will be so much better if apple's guys say some hint on error messages...